# I am confused with this statistical data

Tags: dataset

https://www.statista.com/statistics/254115/favorite-movie-genres-in-the-us/
This graph doesn't make sense to me. Why none of the percentages add up to 100%. How can 62 percent of women choose a genre, but then 80 percent choose another? please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to know for sure without the source. But I suspect that respondents were asked to list more than one genre as their favorite (e.g. "What is your favorite movie genre? (Choose 3)".

Answer (score 4):

I'd assume that the survey allowed multiple choices, e.g. you can choose one or more genres as your favorite.